# JSP Servlet / Activiti - Is there a way to complete 2 tasks at once by submitting 2 forms at once?

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets, activiti

I'm making a web app, that uses Activiti, that has 2 parallel tasks that I want the user to be able to complete at once. I'm not quite sure how to do this though. I've toyed with the idea of submitting one big form that will then be split on the server but I'm not sure how to go about this. I ideally submitting 2 forms at once seems like the logical way but I'm not sure if this is even possible.

My JSP form:

```
<form action="CompleteTask" method="post">
                    <c:forEach items="${formProperties}" var="property" varStatus="status">
                        ${property.getName()}:
                        <br />
                        <c:set var="type" value="${property.getType().getName()}" />
                            <c:if test="${type == 'string'}">
                                <c:if test="${property.isRequired() == 'true' }">
                                    <input type="text" name="${property.getId()}" value="${property.getValue()}" required /><br />
                                </c:if>
                                <c:if test="${property.isRequired() == 'false' }">
                                    <input type="text" name="${property.getId()}" value="" /><br />
                                </c:if>
                            </c:if>
                            <c:if test="${type == 'long'}">
                                <c:if test="${property.isRequired() == 'true' }">
                                    <input type="text" name="${property.getId()}" value="${property.getValue()}" required /><br />
                                </c:if>
                                <c:if test="${property.isRequired() == 'false' }">
                                    <input type="text" name="${property.getId()}" value="" /><br />
                                </c:if>
                            </c:if>
                            <c:if test="${type == 'date'}">
                                <c:if test="${property.isRequired() == 'true' }">
                                    <input type="date" name="${property.getId()}" value="" required /><br />
                                </c:if>
                                <c:if test="${property.isRequired() == 'false' }">
                                    <input type="date" name="${property.getId()}" value="" /><br />
                                </c:if>
                            </c:if>
                            <c:if test="${type == 'enum'}">
                                <select name="${property.getId()}">
                                    <c:forEach var="entry" items='${property.getType().getInformation("values")}'>
                                        <option value="${entry.key}">${entry.value}</option>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </select><br /><br />
                            </c:if>
                    </c:forEach>
                    <input type="hidden" id="taskId" name="taskId" value="${taskList.get(0).getId()}" /><br />
                </form>
```

This form is in a forEach loop so multiple versions are made depending on how many tasks there are (2 in this case).

My current servlet code for completing tasks:

```
ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Enumeration<String> parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();

        while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {

            String paramName = parameterNames.nextElement();

            String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);

            String paramValue = paramValues[0];

            if(!paramName.equals("submit")){

                System.out.println(paramName+ " - " + paramValue);
                params.put(paramName, paramValue);

            }

        }

        String taskId = request.getParameter("taskId");

        TaskService taskService = processEngine.getTaskService();
        Task t = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskId(taskId).singleResult();
        taskService.complete(t.getId(), params);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right - it's better to create one request and then run 2 processes on the server side. However you have to synchronize these processes, get both answers and then combine them to one full answer.

Another way would be to make 2 [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) calls. But in this case you have to do similar synchronization on the client (browser) side.

However, in general, better way would be to simplify your design and have simple and single request/response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the business case that requires a parallel process but only a single user task. Seems you could collect the information you need and branch after that. However, if the business logic is such that you must use this pattern, then BPMN does support the capability with messaging/signals.
Use a single user form on one of the parallel paths. Other paths do not have a user task, rather they are waiting for a message or signal.
Then after collecting the details you need, use a signal send event task to "release" the other parallel paths.